# Start and wait for new thread without blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, join, task

I have a method that can’t run asynchronously. In order not to block the UI thread, I want to open a new thread and run the method in it. However, this thread must be waited for the additional code to be executed according to the method to work. The method that cannot run asynchronously converts a file and it takes some time depending on how big the file is. But I want the window to remain usable, so that the UI thread is not blocked. I have already searched on the Internet, but found nothing suitable.

Comment: If you don't want to block the UI, you obvisously cannot wait for the background thread. What you can do is that the background thread when finished, calls back to the UI (details depend on UI technology) and then the UI can adapt its state accordingly.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't run the method asynchronously"?

Comment: In addition to Henk's great answer, I suggest putting a ProgressBar on your form.  Set its [Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style?view=netcore-3.1) property to Marquee, which is just a continuous indicator that something is happening.  The ProgressBar would initially be invisible.  In the button click handler, make the ProgressBar visible, then hide it again when the task is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
async void button1_Click(....)
{
   label1.Text = "busy...";
   await Task.Run(() => { RunOldCode(); });
   label1.Text = "done.";   // safe to use the UI
}
```

Note that `async void` should only be used for (simple) eventhandlers. It is problematic in most other situations.

Comment: You should probably DISABLE the button as well, then enable it again when the task is done...

Comment: @Idle_Mind - unless this is something that could/should run multiple instances. We just don't know for sure.

Comment: Doesn’t this just do async trickery to keep the same thread usable, but decidedly *not* spin up a separate thread like the OP requested?

Comment: @BenderBoy: No.

Comment: why does this work but: await RunOldCode(); freezes the UI? I understand Task.Run puts the long task on a background thread but both await the result...

Comment: @SteveW RunOldCode() can't be executed async. So there is no await available.